# Como separar uma string em unity c#

Tags: c#, string, unity-5

Queria saber como separar uma string em unity C#, acabei olhando algumas perguntas parecidas para C# soque não em unity, achei muitas vezes esse exemplo

```
string[] linha = reader.ReadLine().Split(new string[] { "||" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

e da erro de que a função `StringSplitOptions` não existe no contexto, então gostaria de saber um método.

Eis o que quero fazer, eu terei em um arquivo TXT uma linha de texto que eu quero separar por o texo para cada || , Ex:

```
" Você acorda, o que faz?||Dormir mais||2||Levantar||1||Sentar e esperar||2||Cair da cama||3$2||1<> "
```

quero separar este texto da seguinte forma;

```
string lin1 = "Você acorda, o que faz?"
string lin2 = "Dormir mais"
string lin3 = "2"
string lin4 = "Levantar"
string lin5 = "1"
string lin6 = "Sentar e esperar"
string lin7 = "2"
string lin8 = "Cair da cama"
string lin9 = "3$2"
string lin10 = "1"
```

Obs: o <> em teoria é para servir como quebra de linha;

Comment: Jovem, conseguiu resolver seu problema? A resposta atendeu o que você precisava ou precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece é que Unity roda numa versão bem antiga do Mono. E nesta versão, algumas coisas que estamos acostumados não estão implementadas.

O método `Split`, nesta versão, não tem nenhuma sobrecarga que aceite como parâmetro um *array* de *strings* e um `StringSplitOptions`.

Em contrapartida, existe uma sobrecarga que aceita um *array* de *chars* e um `StringSplitOptions`.

Neste caso, será impossível quebrar o texto a cada par de *pipes* (`|`), mas como você estará usando a opção `RemoveEmptyEntries`, acaba-se tendo o mesmo resultado final.

```
reader.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oUQQ7Y)

Comment: Obrigado!!, funcionou perfeitamente agora.